# Writing app with multiple panels for OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have a regular OS X app (not document-based) that opens image and shows some additional data in separate views.
I want to refactor the same app so that it will use separate panels (or windows) instead of each view.
The panels should have captions and usual window controls.
I do not want this to be a document-based application.
How can it be done?

Update: this is how I do it

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

self.pwc=[[SomeWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"SomeWindowController"];
[self.pwc showWindow:self.pwc];
```

The *SomeWindowController* is derived from NSWindowController

On last line the app crashes. So what is the correct way to deploy additional window?

Comment: Read the documentation for NSWindowController.

Comment: How do you create the window and the views?

Comment: Accordingly to what I found in the Net: window with all views is defined in .xib file. I  instantiate it in AppDelegate::applicationWillFinishLaunching  and then I don't know how to present it properly. I updated the question body for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason of crash. The window contained QLCompactPreview object and in process of initialization it failed.
When I removed the preview the new window appeared.